# Blocked HTTP Methods are not returning HTTP 405 response

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

How do I configure (ideally) Apache (or alternatively) PHP to respond *specifically* with an **HTTP 405** when the request method is not `GET` or `POST`?

My Apache `.htaccess` attempt does block requests except it returns the incorrect HTTP *403* response:

```
<LimitExcept GET POST>
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</LimitExcept>
```

In PHP I've used the following at the absolute start of where requests are handled and it just gets completely ignored:

```
if (!in_array($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'],array('GET','POST')))
{
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
 header('HTTP/1.1 405');
 die();
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can just put rewrite rule for non GET|POST that will redirect to PHP script that will throw error?

Comment: _“In PHP I've used […]”_ - you mean, in combination with the .htaccess blocking the request from reaching that script in the first place?

Comment: @anubhava The follow-up question can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62666053/force-rewriterule-to-end-processing-looping-in-htaccess-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below redirect rule to disable method and return 405 error code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(POST|GET)$
RewriteRule .* - [R=405]
```

Comment: This works *except* there is another `RewriteRule` further down that when I `#` comment out works though when left in makes a regular `PUT` request turn in to an HTTP 302 response. I attempted to modify the line with an `L,` (`RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]`) though it does not prevent the `PUT` request from processing the rest of the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Use separate rewrite conditions and rules and test. Add suggested rule inside VirtualHost and test.

Comment: It works on it's own but another rule negates it so I'll ask a separate question to address that issue. `[END]` and `[L]` combinations do absolutely nothing regardless of their order or the order of the rules. When I remove that second unrelated rule it does work hence why I'm accepting this answer. Thank you.

Comment: Follow-up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62666053/force-rewriterule-to-end-processing-looping-in-htaccess-file