# Force RewriteRule to end processing/looping in htaccess file

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, httpresponse, apache2.4, http-status-code-405

Yesterday I discovered that my server's response to non-supported HTTP methods was incorrect. If an HTTP method is not supported you're supposed to respond with an `HTTP 405: Method Not Supported`. Pandurang was able to [answer that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62652001/blocked-http-methods-are-not-returning-http-405-response).

I've done a lot of reading about how `[L]` loops and I had spent time going through all the [Apache 2.4 flag documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html).

- I tried using the `[L]` flag and then the `[END]` flag.
- I tried to combine flags in every possible way (e.g. `[L,R=405]`, `[END,R=405]`) on both `RewriteRule` sets.
- I tried combinations where flags where absent.
- I rearranged the order of the rules.
- I tried adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(GET|POST)$` before the unrelated second `RewriteRule`.
- I did a *lot* of reading.

Here are the two set of rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(GET|POST)$
RewriteRule .* - [R=405]

#Unrelated rule, when present, breaks the above HTTP 405 turning it in to an HTTP 302:
RewriteRule !\.(css|js|zip)$ index.php [L]
```

To do testing I ran the following command using cURL:

```
curl -X PUT -d arg=val -d arg2=val2 https://www.example.com/ -i
```

I know the HTTP 405 code works via cURL because I can see the response code, just *not* when the other line is present and I *have to have both*. What do I need to do to force Apache to stop looping/processing once it matches a rule?

Comment: @anubhava As I've mentioned, the unrelated rule (at the bottom) when removed allows the HTTP 405 to work correctly. Their relative position, flags, etc have all been adjusted but I have to have both the unrelated `RewriteRule` and this to block non-supported methods.

Comment: Very strange because I copy pasted exact same code in my local .htaccess (with 2nd rule as well) and I still get `405` not `302`

Comment: LiteSpeed would mess with `RewriteRule` sometimes but I just confirmed it's not on the live server. I know order of rules is important, I just am at a complete loss. What else can I try?

Comment: Oh, I just removed almost everything and put the 405 code below the unrelated and it worked...now I have to hunt down some sort of combination, will update in a minute...

Comment: Jfyi: I have `405` rule at top and it is working fine on my `Apache 2.4.43`

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the new code *must* be at the bottom, which makes no sense as I'd like to avoid having Apache process all of the other rules to only end up doing this.

```
#Unrelated rule
RewriteRule !\.(css|js|zip)$ index.php [L]

#Rule that now works, only at the bottom
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(GET|POST)
RewriteRule .* - [R=405,L]
```